# Using SendGrid to send password reset links

Tags: sendgrid

I am using SendGrid as the email provider in my application. When I place a link in the email it gets re-encoded to a link on the SendGrid servers. Can I trust this link with my password resets? I know that I am already trusting SendGrid with my links by sending through their servers but what is the purpose of rewriting the urls. To use the link you need to also know the email address and it is only valid for 20 minutes.

The link in my email looks like

http://myserver/resetpassword/oLsjShCLh7tFpyl8cEzbghHpS59iazhD

and it gets encoded in the email as

https://u5478763.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=hvVg2ntCa8InWO5OtVSRJPdvIiofcS3RGII270TrJ9aOSJX2MZ9RkcgQLgnRLLNMjjo5mMQVejYxIGVPoz-2BfxtM55lXWiXwtNWvE42LzFPE-3D_Q0Y0L54uOhrrHtFzGFlMm55yZkDAUn39DjKFOTu4BtReZW14K4ruKT7IkXyh4pWHctN-2FYlmmFj2J7a6-2BHy0UN0PZDTzqKnADTi10YJeXfirMSGqGLkjKxZZY1iGRjCkgddBCiyIBiLfBs3VS4GmrB5SPa7uCb9KYcZdqm5AvebY6pyGitqdcpmDSVV6zHjR1oK3NZQboFfjng-2Fqv6PQHekU7irw1BWOtP5ja3RxfUKE-3D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have `Click Tracking` enabled in your account. Log into your SendGrid dashboard, and from the navbar on the left side click on `Settings` -> `Tracking` and disable `Click Tracking`.

Comment: I am facing a wired issue, when password reset email is send to customer, dot is missing from password reset link. This is happening 1 out of 100 emails hence we could not able to reproduce it in local. We are using ActionMailer with Ruby on Rails using SendGrid provider. Do you have idea on where to look and how to fix this issue.

Comment: @user2086641 Sorry, I haven't been keeping up with SendGrid for a long time. You would probably get an answer if you contact their support.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. They are asking us to turn off click tracking, which the product manager won't accept. Searching for a solution yet.